# How to fire my jQuery on resize and detect the width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this script that I wrote but I need help. It's suppose to work like a off-canvas menu for mobile/tablets

The issue is that if i resize the browser and open up the menu again the marginLeft of -270px isn't ideal since if i resize the browser the -270px of the original mark don't match up since its a different viewport size.

Right now I am pushing the body to the left using `marginLeft:-270px` this works fine on load BUT if i resize the browser everything gets all buggy.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
jQuery('.menu-toggle').toggle(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('open');
        jQuery('#top-main-nav-container').addClass('active');

        jQuery('body').animate({
          marginLeft: '-270'
        }, 700);
        jQuery('.main-navigation ul').css('display','block');

      },function() {
         jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
         jQuery('#top-main-nav-container').removeClass('active');

         jQuery('body').animate({
           marginLeft: '0'
         }, 700);

         jQuery('.main-navigation ul').css('display','none');

      });`
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-toggle.open {
    padding: 30px 25px 500% 100%; 
    background-color: rgba(165, 166, 168, 0.952941);
}
body.active {
    margin:0;
    -moz-transition: margin .5s;
    -webkit-transition: margin .5s;
    transition: margin .5s;
}
#top-main-nav-container.active {
    right:0;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

Comment: $(window).resize(function(){      /*your fn here*/              })

Comment: see https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: i have tried this but it needs to work on load and resize. @joyBlanks

Comment: Add the the code which you used for window resize event

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {

    // Invoke the resize event immediately
    }).resize();
```

The last `.resize()` call will run this code upon load.

**OR**

The cleanest way is to just  bind it also to the load event:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {

});
```